# Firefox changes my url?

Tags: firefox

maybe there is a trivial solution but I have not found it. when I type an intranet url such as http://name/path Firefox replaces it with http://www.name.com/path and reports an error saying that it cannot find this server. how can I stop it from being so "smart"?

Comment: Did you really actually include the `http://`? If so, then folks below referring to DNS are probably right. But when *not* including that `http://` then what if you add that yourself?

Answer (score 16):

1. Type `about:config` into the address bar.
2. Type `fixup` into the "Filter" box.
3. Double-click `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` to change its value to `false`.

(I see I also have `google.toolbar.linkdoctor.backup.browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` which doesn't seem to have any effect on my browser, but maybe you'll need to disable that as well.)

Comment: This was driving me nuts. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try to ping the server name, so you will be sure that `hostname` is added in the `DNS` registry.

This behavior gets done when a `hostname` it's not available.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the host not being available in your DNS system.

It looks like your example of http://name/path is to a local server name, possibly in your local network.

Perhaps you are missing the local network in your DNS search "suffixes" or from /etc/resolv.conf on unix.

Try using the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) for the host, if that works, ensure you have the appropriate DNS search suffixes defined in your network configuration.

Hope this helps for you.

Comment: Yes it is not in the DNS **for me**, but then when I add it. It still does not work, as now pointing to wrong place.